# "For," "In," or "On," in terms of ROI

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> $900 billion is still considerably larger than most can comprehend, but the actual return on investment ***for*** space exploration is considerably higher than any other existing industry.

In this sentence, is "***for***" the correct word?

Should it instead be:

> ... the actual return on investment ***in*** space exploration is ...

or

> ... the actual return on investment ***on*** space exploration is ...

In this case, "[return on investment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_on_investment)" (ROI) is an economic phrase, and I think that's what has me confused.

Comment: I'd go with *from*.

Comment: @PhilSweet investment from space exploration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the three prepositions are used, with *for and in* as the more common (see ***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=return%20on%20investment%20on%2Creturn%20on%20investment%20in%2Creturn%20on%20investment%20for&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creturn%20on%20investment%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creturn%20on%20investment%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creturn%20on%20investment%20for%3B%2Cc0)***).

I'd personally use *"investment return **in** (the field of) space exploration"*, but "for" is also correct.

Comment: Many of the "for" examples aren't analogous, as in "this strategy resulted in a poor return on investment for the client."

Answer (score 0):

"ROI of" is another variation. It ranks on top of the [Ngram Viewer.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ROI%20on%2CROI%20in%2CROI%20for%2CROI%20of&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2CROI%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CROI%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CROI%20for%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CROI%20of%3B%2Cc0)
[image]

Comment: But the object of the preposition "of" is not the thing being invested in but rather the value of the return, as in "an ROI of 50%."  So that doesn't help answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it this way: "for" works because you can say "for space exploration, the return on investment is higher."  Similarly, "in" works because you can say "investment in space exploration yields a higher return."

In other words, the bit following "investment" can relate just to the word "investment" or to the phrase "return on investment."

Answer (score 0):

> In this sentence, is "for" the correct word?

Yes.

For = for the purpose of;

the actual return [on .....investment.] [for.. space ...exploration]

Det..adj...noun...[prep........noun...]... [prep....noun...noun....]

.......................[pp modifying return]. [pp modifying investment]

The investment is made **for the purpose of**, or in relation to space exploration

OED

> **IV. Of purpose or destination.**
>
> **8.a. With a view to; with the object or purpose of: as preparatory to.**
>
> 1849   T. B. Macaulay Hist. Eng. I. 615   *A considerable number of prisoners were immediately selected for execution.*